# Add/Remove class if checkbox is checked/unchecked (AngularJS)

Tags: angularjs, checkbox, input, angularjs-scope, angular-ngmodel

I need to toggle a class if a checkbox is checked/unchecked with AngularJS. My Code is working on Plunker but in my controller there is no functionality.

Here is the Plunker: [Click!](http://plnkr.co/edit/OFKkaJjhBcjSTWmyLRLQ?p=preview)

My Controller looks like this:

```
angular.module('inspinia')
.controller('MainController', function ($location, $scope, $state) {

  // initialize iCheck
  angular.element('.i-checks').iCheck({
    checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_square-green',
    radioClass: 'iradio_square-green'
  });

  //Checkbox functionality
  $scope.isChecked = function() {
      if ($scope.checked) {
        return false;
      }else{
        return true;
      }
  };

});
```

HTML

```
          <div class="panel panel-default confirm-panel accept-terminplanung">
            <div class="panel-body text-muted ibox-heading">
              <form action="#" method="post" role="form">
                <div class="i-checks" iCheck>
                  <label class="">
                    <div class="icheckbox_square-green">
                      <input type="checkbox" class="i-checks" ng-model="checked">
                    </div>
                      <p class="no-margins">Hiermit  akzeptiere ich  die Bedingungen des geschlossenen Dozentenvertrages und nehme den Bildungsauftrag für die ausgewählten Ausbildungen verbindlich an.</p>
                  </label>
                </div>
                <button type="button" name="termin-bestaetigen" class="btn btn-w-m btn-warning submit-appointment disabled" ng-class="{disabled: isChecked()}">Terminplanung übernehmen</button>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't understand what's the problem. Plunkr works fine!

Comment: @HorstJahns Yup, the Punkr is working fine, but it doesn't work inside my controller. That was the question..

Comment: your controller is part of the plunkr and it still works...

Comment: @HorstJahns ..no its not. I'm using a test controller in plunkr. My Controller looks like this: .controller('MainController', function ($location, $scope, $state){...});

Comment: so how should we tell you why it does not work in your controller, if you do not show your controller?

Comment: @HorstJahns I updated the code..

Comment: and your template uses ng-controller="MainController"?

Comment: @HorstJahns yup..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can understand from the provided piece of code iCheck is something that is not working in `angular` scope, like JQuery. So every time your value inside this component changes you need to trigger a `$digest` cycle with a use of `$scope.$digest()` or `$scope.$apply()`.

In iCheck documentation you can find callbacks section, so you can subscribe to that event and do `$scope.$apply()` in it.
For example, inside your controller:

```
<your-iCheck-element>.on('ifChecked', function(event){
  $scope.$apply();
});
```

Comment: ..youre right. Without the iCheck-Plugin the code is working. But how can I trigger a $digest? I never did that before..

Answer (score 0):

Your function is basically doing nothing, but giving back the opposite value of checked. You can simply use negation of your model.

```
ng-class="{disabled: !checked}"
```

Comment: ..nope, it doesnt change anything :(